# Fatal error: Call to undefined method connectDB::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried to do a simple CRUD using a class connectDB to connect to a MySQL database. Then when I try to execute the method delRecipe of the class RecipesModel the system show me an error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method connectDB::prepare()

Is the right way to call the method prepare()? Why is not recognized?

Here is the code of connectDB (file connectDB.php)

```
class connectDB {

    private $address='localhost';
    private $db_name='db-name';
    private $user='root';
    private $pswd='psswd';

    private $sql;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->sql = new mysqli($this->address,$this->user,$this->pswd,$this->db_name);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Error de Conexion: '. mysqli_connect_errno().' - '.mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        return $this->sql;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if(!mysqli_close($this->sql)) {
            die('ERROR!:'.$this->sql->error);
        }
    }

    public function execute($query) {
        $res = $this->sql->query($query);
        if ($res) {
            return $res;    
        }
        else {
            die('ERROR!:'.$this->sql->error);
        }
    }
}
```

And the class that delete the row.

```
<?php
require_once('connectDB.php');

class RecipesModel {

    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new connectDB();
    }

    public function delRecipe($id) {
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM t_platos WHERE ID_pl= ?';
            $this->db->prepare($sql);
            return $this->db->execute(array($id));
        }
    }
}

$recipe = new RecipesModel();
$res = $recipe->delRecipe(1);

?>
```

Comment: You dont have a `prepare` method in your DBConnect class !!!!

Comment: The MYSQLI extension has a perfectly good OO access method. You will only complictate things trying to RE-Wrap it in your own

Comment: Here is a free piece of advice: stop making wrappers for connection abstractions. They are pointless. Also, read up about dependency injection. Oh .. and don't call them "models". What you have there are just improvisation on [active record](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `connectDB` class does not **have** a method called `prepare()`.

You're probably trying to call `$this->db->sql->prepare()`, since in `connectDB` you store the actual database connection into `$this->sql`. However, since the `$sql` property is `private`, you can't do that.

You'll either need to make `$sql` a `public` property, or create a method in your `connectDB` class to act as a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Your misunderstanding is this:

```
    return $this->sql;
```

You can't `return` something of your choice in a constructor. The value returned by a constructor is always the object instance of that class.