# MySQLi - Call to undefined method ::prepare()

Tags: php, mysqli

First of all, on SO there are a couple of questions asked about this subject. However, the most useful ones are about PDO, where I use MySQLi. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44477331/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-connectdbprepare) gets close, but I cannot seem to get it working for my situation. Hence this question.

I try to use prepared statements for processing user input in a HTML form. This is posted to process.php:

```
class connect{
    public $connection;

    function db_connect(){
      $this->connection = mysqli_connect(xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx);
      return $this->connection;
    }

$con = new connect();
$con->db_connect();

$keyword = $_POST["value"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE ?";

$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $keyword);
$stmt->execute();
```

This throws the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   connect::prepare() in process.php:27

where line 27 contains `$stmt = $con->prepare($query);`

I'm afraid the answer to this question might be shamefully simple, but your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You’re trying to call the method on your class `connect` as the error says. It doesn’t have a `prepare` method. You should call it on the object it returns.

Comment: You probably mean `$con->connection->prepare()`

Comment: Try not to wrap `mysqli` up in some other layer. If you need abstraction use an ORM.

Comment: is `$con` something returned from` mysqli_connect()` ? I don't think so. I think it should be something like `$connection = $con->db_connect()` on line 21

Comment: @tadman, sounds like I could learn from this, what do you mean with that?

Comment: There's packaged solutions like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) that can help intermediate between your code and the raw SQL layer. Writing your own by accident happens far more often than we as developers are prepared to admit.

Comment: Three people places the same answer at the same time. It works great now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$con` does not contain the database connection.

It should be

```
$connection = $con->db_connect();
```

`db_connect()` returns the actual database connection

Then use `$connection` to access mysqli functions such as `prepare()`

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
```

Answer (score 4):

You never assign the results of `$con->db_connect()` to a variable. `$con` remains the class `connect`. Either assign the results to a variable `$connection = $con->db_connect();` and use the `$connection` variable, or use public `$connection` property of the `connect()` class:

```
$statement = $con->connection->prepare(...);
```